# How to find the position where two arrays have the same numbers?

Tags: arrays, c, compare

So I'm trying to make a guessing program in C, where the user has to input 5 numbers and the computer generates 5 random numbers. My code for the user to input the numbers is this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SIZE; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", &(userGuess[i]));
}
```

I want to output the positions where the user input was right so for example if user input `2 3 4 5 7` and the computer's 5 random number was `2 3 9 8 7` it would print out `correct position(s): 0, 1, 4`
This is what I have currently tried, but it can only print `0, 1` and when it tries to print a number after it skipped on like in the example I put, it would print 0, 0, and a long random number.

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SIZE; ++i){
        if (userGuess[i] == winNum[i]) {
            matchedPos[i] = i;
        }
}
```

Comment: Just as a side note: It is unsafe to use `scanf` without checking the return value. See this page for further information: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with exact input, expected output and actual output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you never initialized the elements of `matchedPos` for elements that the user didn't guess right. You need to initialize all the array elements.

Also, there's no point in putting `i` into the `matchedPos` array, since it's the same as the array index. Instead, assign `0` or `1` depending on whether the guess matches. Then you just print the indexes that contain `1`.

```
int matchedPos[NUM_SIZE];

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SIZE; i++) {
    matchedPos[i] = userGuess[i] == winNum[i];
}

printf("Correct guesses: ");
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SIZE; i++) {
    if (matchedPos[i]) {
        printf("%d ", i);
    }
printf("\n");
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I did initialize `matchedPos[NUM_SIZE]`, but I didn't show it on my question, my bad. It was my print statement that was wrong- I was just printing the elements in array which was printing the numbers where the positions were not the same. I just need commas in the print statement, but I already know how to do that, thanks again!